# How to force Linux only use Socks5 instead of Socks4

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, socks-proxy, socks

I used command gsettings to set proxy mode to be 'manual',
proxy.socks host '127.0.0.1'
proxy.socks port 1080,
Test program received socks4 and socks5 packets.
Socks5 is only used on the packet which contained an IPv6 address.
How to force Linux only use socks5?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
It's not about proxy settings.
It's firefox. If wanna use firefox to send socks5 by default, it needs a browser addon.
refer to: https://github.com/BackupGGCode/dsocks/blob/60476a52f544f7745f078943e1b0422a61dbd779/dsocks.sh
Switch to chrome, everything's fine.